# BigQuery - Adwords Data Transfer - AccountStats vs AccountBasicStats

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

For many tables, there's always a AccountStats vs AccountBasicStats.

The same SQL query might have different values from Stats vs BasicStats, for example:

```
SELECT
  cs.Date,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Sum_Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Clicks) AS Sum_Clicks,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Sum_Interactions,
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS Sum_Cost,
  SUM(cs.Conversions) AS Sum_Conversions
FROM
  `{dataset_id}.Customer_{customer_id}` c
LEFT JOIN
  `{dataset_id}.AccountBasicStats_{customer_id}` cs
  <-----OR USING----->
  `{dataset_id}.AccountStats_{customer_id}` cs
ON
  c.ExternalCustomerId = cs.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
  AND c.ExternalCustomerId = {customer_id}
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1
```

It seems the main difference is ClickType column, which might double count based on the documentation: [ClickType](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/account-performance-report#clicktype).

The BasicStats seems the most accurate, and match up exactly from adwords. While the Stats give around 2x-3x increase in impressions.

Is there a way to transform the data so that both queries would get the same results?

Since there's no basic stats for Hourly data, which I'm interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/QiY_RT9aNlM

Seems that there is no way to de-segment the data after ClickType is brought in.