# Transfer Service Data Discrepancy: Google Ads (AdWords) <> BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-ads-api

Has anyone had issues with data from Google Ads data transferred to BigQuery?

I used the Google Ads transfer service and while validating the transferred data by querying it, I noticed discrepancies between what I see in the Google Ads web portal and what has been transferred to BigQuery. Some of the discrepancies are quite egregious.

I have contacted Google Cloud support, BigQuery specialist phone support, Google Ads API team, and every single one of them has pointed me to someone else. I'm hoping that I can [reach one of the engineers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support) here or someone who can clarify if this is expected or not.

While click and cost data is mostly ok (not completely clear of discrepancies), there is not one day in which the impression data matches with what I see online. Not even close. It's my understanding that recent data can change a bit while all of the data is processed, so I looked at data from the past too.

I even tried account for timezone difference between UTC and Eastern US.

Below are two queries I used. The first one grouping by day and the other one trying to see if adjusting for timezone made any difference.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  _PARTITIONTIME as pt,
  SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions,
  SUM(ActiveViewImpressions) AS ActImpressions,
  SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks,
  (SUM(Cost)/1000000) AS Cost
FROM
  `12345.supermetrics.p_AdStats_[ACCT_ID]`
GROUP BY
  pt
ORDER BY
 pt DESC
```

.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  newDate,
  SUM(Impressions) as Impressions,
  SUM(Clicks) as clicks,
  SUM(Cost) as Cost
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Impressions,
    Clicks,
    (Cost / 1000000) as Cost,
    CAST(TIMESTAMP_ADD( TIMESTAMP(Date), INTERVAL (HourofDay - 5) HOUR) AS DATE) AS newDate
  FROM
    `12345.supermetrics.p_HourlyAdGroupStats_[ACCT_ID]`
)
GROUP BY
  newDate
ORDER BY
  newDate ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

I found two reasons for discrepancies:

1. Backfill end date not set properly: It is 'exclusive', i.e. it is the first day for which no data will be fetched.
2. Conversion window: The Google Ads Transfer has a standard refresh window of 7 days. If in Google Ads your window is set the the standard 30 days, any conversions occurring after seven to 30 days after the click will not be in BQ. This may also affect other data that is later changed by Google, e.g. impressions, clicks and/or cost due to click fraud.

You can adjust the refresh window in the transfer settings. There is no daily backfill if set to 1. Value 0 indicates default refresh window (7 days).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I think that you're spot on.

Answer (score 1):

The higher (incorrect) count of impressions happens in tables that have the segment `ClickType` as a column.

To get the correct number of impressions use table `AdBasicStats` instead of `AdStats`.

Same happens with similar tables such as `AccountStats` vs `AccountBasicStats` etc.

See also these SO questions:
[Google Ads Impressions count in BigQuery is not the same as in the Google Ads Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855906/google-ads-impressions-count-in-bigquery-is-not-the-same-as-in-the-google-ads-re)

[BigQuery - Adwords Data Transfer - AccountStats vs AccountBasicStats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429498/bigquery-adwords-data-transfer-accountstats-vs-accountbasicstats)

More info on ClickType:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/account-performance-report#clicktype